# Update a row if insert was already done

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this SQL:

```
$s_sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO %s (id, id_jack, start_time, end_time)
                      VALUES (%d, %d, '%s', '%s') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE start_time = '%s', end_time = '%s'",
        'table',
        $id,
        $id_jack,
        $startDate,
        $endDate,
        $startDate,
        $endDate);
```

I want if I have already in table the inscription with the `id` and `id_jack` I want to update only the start and end time. Can you help me please? Now I have only the inserts on each call.

Comment: I did not undestand what you mean!

Comment: So what's the question? Have you tried what you have above? Are you getting errors?

Answer (score 0):

Your query should basically be ok . . . although you should be using parameters for all the values.  I would write this as:

```
INSERT INTO %s (id, id_jack, start_time, end_time)
    VALUES (%d, %d, '%s', '%s')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE start_time = VALUES(start_time)
                            end_time = VALUES(end_time);
```

That way, you don't have to duplicate the arguments (which can lead to errors).

For this to work, you need a unique index/primary key.  I am not sure if you need one on `(id, id_jack)` or two `(id)` and `(id_jack)`.  However, these need to be created separately from the above query:

```
create unique index unq_t_id_idjack on t(id, idjack);
```